# understanding x86-64 call operand

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm looking at some test code in radare2, and I'm having trouble understanding how disassemblers figure how where a call instruction jumps to.
Consider this:

[image: r2]

at 0x00001090 puts() gets called. I wanted to parse the binary (e89bffffff) associated with that instruction myself, so I ran it through lib capstone and got this:

[image: capstone]

so we can see the actual operand is 0xfb0. And then in rasm2 we have:

```
# rasm2 -a x86 -b 64 -d e8a1ffffff
call 0xffffffffffffffa6
```

which is different. I expected libcapstone and rasm2 to have the same output.

My main question is, how do I interpret 0xfb0 (or 0xffffffffffffffa6) to get the next instruction address? In my case sym.imp.puts is at 0x00001030 according to radare.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call: "displacement relative to next instruction".  I am not sure why there's an overall difference of 0x80 between your two disassemblies, but they're both consistent with the same displacement.

Comment: The operand to call is rip relative, so you need to know where the call instruction is located to decode it correctly.

Comment: By the way, why is your rasm2 command trying to decode `e8a1ffffff` when the instruction from the program was actually `e89bffffff`?

Comment: Also, please do not post pictures of text.  Insted, copy-paste the text into your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown at https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call, the `e8` opcode executes a call with **relative** displacement.  The operand is a signed 32-bit displacement which is added to the address of the next instruction to get the absolute target address.  This is to make it easy to write position-independent code, that will run the same no matter where it is loaded in memory.

The displacement operand here is `9bffffff`.  It's little-endian (like everything on x86) so this is the number `0xffffff9b`, or `-0x65`.

In your first disassembly, the instruction following the `call` instruction is at address `0x00001095`, so the call will go to `0x00001095 - 0x65 = 0x00001030`.  The disassembler has checked the symbol table and seen that this address corresponds to `sym.imp.puts`, so it shows you that instead of the numerical address.

In your second disassembly, the code seems to have been loaded at a different address, and the address of the following instruction is `0x1015`, so the call will go to `0x1015 - 0x65 = 0x0fb0`.  The disassembler has done this calculation for you, and is showing you the actual target address rather than the displacement.

`rasm2` is just given the instruction, without information about the address where it was found, so it can't do this calculation.  Thus it just tells you the displacement.  For some reason it has chosen to sign-extend it to 64 bits.  Also you seem to have made a typo in giving it `e8a1ffffff` instead of the actual instruction `e89bffffff` which is why you are seeing a different displacement.

Comment: In 64-bit mode, `call rel32` does sign-extend the displacement to 64-bit so it's not wrong to show the actual number that will be added to RIP, instead of the 32-bit encoding.  Worth mentioning that all the `jcc` relative jump instructions use the same encoding (but with signed 8-bit displacements, which aren't available for `call`).